# pthread running thread concurrently c

Tags: c, multithreading, pi

I need to make the Leibniz algorithm with pthread in c, now I have this code, but at the moment the threads implementation takes the same time of the sequential implementation, I think it is not running concurrently. Can someone see the error.

Thanks!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 2
#define ITERATIONS 100000000
double result = 0.0;
void *leibniz(void *threadid){
  int size = ITERATIONS/NUM_THREADS;
  int start = (long)threadid * size;
  int end = ((long)threadid+1) * size;
  int i;
  for(i = start; i<end; i++){
    int denom = 2*i+1;
    result += pow(-1.0, i) * (1.0/denom);
  }
}

int main(){
  pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
  long t;
  int rc;

  // CREATE
  for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++){
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, leibniz, (void *)t);
    if(rc){
      printf("ERROR: return code %d\n", rc);
    }
  }
  // JOIN
  for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++){
    rc = pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
    if(rc){
      printf("ERROR: return code %d\n", rc);
      exit(-1);
    }
  }
  printf("Pi %f\n", result*4);
  exit(0);

}
```

Thanks to Jean-François Fabre I did these changes, now it works!

```
double result=0.0;

void *leibniz(void *threadid){
  double local = 0.0;
  int size = ITERATIONS/NUM_THREADS;
  int start = (long)threadid * size;
  int end = ((long)threadid+1) * size;
  int i;
  for(i = start; i<end; i++){
    local += (i%2==0 ? 1 : -1) * (1.0/(2*i+1));
  }
  result += local*4;
}
```

Comment: your thread implementation is not correct: you're accessing the same variable without locking. You should accumulate in each thread, then add to the global variable at the end, using locking.

Comment: also: `pow(-1.0, i)` is just a waste of power. You could do `-1 if i%2 else 1`

Comment: Dear OP, to elaborate @Jean-FrançoisFabre comment... `global variables` are shared among all threads. You might have race condition while multiple threads try to modify the global variable.

Comment: plus I believe it would be faster to use a local variable, more likely to be stored in a register all the way.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre when threads change turns in CPU the register is written to stack. So I think in both cases its the same.

Comment: I don't see how OP gets the proper result with that much concurrent access on the result variable. I would make it local (even without using a mutex) to reduce this concurrent access, even if it's not very good.

Comment: BTW, since there's only floating point addition, and only 1 FPU available, isn't that the bottleneck? would be interesting to add garbage in integers instead and see if it's faster with threads (disregarding the results)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't know it you were asking me :D but as far as I know, it depends, though most of the time floating point addition is indeed slower than integer addition.

Comment: In fact, the code presented computes a different wrong value on every run, just as one would predict from the unsynchronized multi-thread access to a shared variable.

Comment: It gets a 10-20% speedup just from turning `result` into an array with one element for each thread, with the main thread adding up all the partial results at the end.  It gets the right answer that way, too.

Comment: FWIW, I shaved about 80% off the runtime of the single-threaded version, and more than 90% off the runtime of the dual-threaded version.  The most impactful changes were (1) replaced the call to `pow()` with a unary `-` operator; and (2) used a local accumulation variable (copied out to a per-thread global array element at the end).  I also applied a few additional arithmetic simplifications that had a minor impact.  After this, the dual-thread version actually is nearly twice as fast as the single-thread version.  Of course, both versions compute the right answer, unlike the OP's.

Comment: I suspect that the improvement in speedup is attributable mostly to a much lower ratio of FP to integer operations in each loop iteration.

Comment: Also after you fix the code (remove data race and crappy pow function) compile with `-O3 -march=native` or even add `-ffast-math` (it is safe in your case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll attempt to answer.

Even if your application is multithreaded, it's not guaranteed that there's 1 FPU per core. I know little about that but I think that some AMD processors actually *share* the FPU between cores.

Since your loop is basically adding and `pow`, it's 99% FPU computation, so if the FPU is shared on your computer, it explains the bottleneck.

You could reduce FPU usage by not calling `pow` just to compute `-1` or `1`, which would be a scalar operation, and maybe would make a difference then. just use `-1` if `i` is odd, `1` otherwise, or negate an external 1/-1 variable at each iteration.

Also, in order to avoid race conditions, accumulate the result in a local result, and add it in the end (protecting the addition by a mutex in the end would be even better)

```
double result = 0.0;
void *leibniz(void *threadid){
  double local = 0.0;
  int size = ITERATIONS/NUM_THREADS;
  int start = (long)threadid * size;
  int end = ((long)threadid+1) * size;
  int i;
  for(i = start; i<end; i++){
    int denom = 2*i+1;
    // using a ternary/scalar speeds up the "pow" computation, multithread or not
    local += (i%2 ? -1 : 1) * (1.0/denom);
  }
  // you may want to protect that addition with a pthread_mutex
  // start of critical section
  result += local;
  // end of critical section
}
```

http://wccftech.com/amd-one-fpu-per-core-design-zen-processors/

Comment: Hi, Jean, thanks for your answer, I did what you said but I'm still having the same problem, the performance is better, but it doesn't run concurrently. I will edit the code in the post.

Comment: look at John Bollinger comments which improve my input. How can you be sure that it doesn't run concurrently? if you have a bottleneck FPU you cannot be twice as fast with 2 threads anyway.

Comment: Now it works I was trying on a VM that explains why it wasn't working, but your solution was the right, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Visual Studio on Windows, and I haven't installed pthreads, so I created a test program using Windows threads. I split the calculation into one function that calculates all the positive terms and one function that calculates all the negative terms. Double precision is not an issue because the positive sum is < 22, and negative sum is > -19.

The processor is an Intel 3770K 3.5ghz (each core has it's own FPU). I tested calling the two functions in a row versus using a separate thread for the second function and the two thread case is twice as fast as the single thread case, single thread ~ 0.360 seconds, dual thread ~= 0.180 seconds.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

static HANDLE ht1;                      /* thread handle */

static DWORD WINAPI Thread0(LPVOID);    /* thread functions */
static DWORD WINAPI Thread1(LPVOID);

static clock_t ctTimeStart;             /* clock values */
static clock_t ctTimeStop;
static double  dTime;

static double pip;              /* sum of positive terms */
static double pim;              /* sum of negative terms */
static double pi;               /* pi */

int main()
{
    ctTimeStart = clock();
    Thread0(NULL);
    Thread1(NULL);
    ctTimeStop = clock();
    dTime = (double)(ctTimeStop - ctTimeStart) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);  
    pip *= 4.;          /* pip <  22 after *= 4. */
    pim *= 4.;          /* pim > -19 after *= 4. */
    pi = pip + pim;
    printf("%.16lf %.16lf %.16lf %2.5lf secs\n", pi, pip, pim, dTime);

    ctTimeStart = clock();
    ht1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Thread1, 0, 0, 0);
    Thread0(NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(ht1, INFINITE); // wait for thead 1
    ctTimeStop = clock();
    dTime = (double)(ctTimeStop - ctTimeStart) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);  
    pip *= 4.;          /* pip <  22 after *= 4. */
    pim *= 4.;          /* pim > -19 after *= 4. */
    pi = pip + pim;
    printf("%.16lf %.16lf %.16lf %2.5lf secs\n", pi, pip, pim, dTime);

    CloseHandle(ht1);

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI Thread0(LPVOID lpVoid)
{
double pp = 0.;                         /* local sum */
int j;
    for(j = 200000001; j >= 0; j -= 4)
        pp += 1. / (double)(j);
    pip = pp;                           /* store sum */
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI Thread1(LPVOID lpVoid)
{
double pm = 0.;                         /* local sum */
int j;
    for(j = 200000003; j >= 0; j -= 4)
        pm -= 1. / (double)(j);
    pim = pm;                           /* store sum */
    return 0;
}
```